# vue.js dynamic route regex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a problem. I need that last route regex not match product1 and product. Last route must open in different component.

This case not working.

```
{path: '/products/product1/:name?', component: product1},
{path: '/products/product2/:name?/:another?', component: product2},

{path: '/products/?!:category(/product1|product2/)/:name?/:another?', component: main},
```